# How to keep two divs and images inside them to be side by side on browser resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ao9k1m20/4/

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper{
    width:470px; 
    float:left; 
    height:637px;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left; border:5px solid #187BB7;
  background-size:auto; 
  height:610px;
}
#container1{
    background-image:url(http://i2.wp.com/theultralinx.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/tumblr_njxiyeoMUt1qkegsbo1_500.jpg?resize=450%2C610);
}
#container2{
    background-image:url(http://decoratedlife.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/pinterest-small-room.jpg);
}
img.info-icon{
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1001;
  background-color:white;
}
#container1 .info-icon1{
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  left: 250px;
}
#container1 .info-icon2{
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
#container1 .info-icon3{
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 80px;
}
#container2 .info-icon1{
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  left: 250px;
}
#container2 .info-icon2{
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
#container2 .info-icon3{
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 80px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!--Left Col-->
      <div class="container" id="container1">
          <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/gakuseisean/ivista-2/24/Start-Menu-Search-icon.png" alt="info" class="info-icon info-icon1" data-target="pop5"  />
          <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/gakuseisean/ivista-2/24/Start-Menu-Search-icon.png" alt="info" class="info-icon info-icon2" data-target="pop5"  />
          <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/gakuseisean/ivista-2/24/Start-Menu-Search-icon.png" alt="info" class="info-icon info-icon3" data-target="pop5"  />
      </div>

        <!--Right Col-->
        <div class="container" id="container2">
            <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/gakuseisean/ivista-2/24/Start-Menu-Search-icon.png" alt="info" class="info-icon info-icon1" data-target="pop5"  />
          <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/gakuseisean/ivista-2/24/Start-Menu-Search-icon.png" alt="info" class="info-icon info-icon2" data-target="pop5"  />
          <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/gakuseisean/ivista-2/24/Start-Menu-Search-icon.png" alt="info" class="info-icon info-icon3" data-target="pop5"  />
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

It has two float divs lined up together but when the browser is resized (not maximized or if it is being viewed in ipad/tablet) then the other div goes down.
I want to show it side by side for comparison like after-before, with some pointer images which are when clicked shows a detail popup.

My question is how can i resize both of the divs in such a way they remain side by side and that the small pointers inside them are also resized and positioned correctly when the browser is resized or when the site is being viewed inside a tablet/ipad?

Please advice, thx!

Comment: You use responsive design. Instead of using `position:absolute;` and fixed `width` values. Your content should be `position:relative;` and `width:50%;` (if you want them side by side) This way they take up 50% of their container.

Comment: This may be a good start - [http://jsfiddle.net/ao9k1m20/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/ao9k1m20/5/)

Comment: @LShetty thank you for the fix, its nearly to what i wanted, its just clips the background when window is resized (when you are watching this on ipad/tablet). How can we prevent this from happening? Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see if this suits your need. I apply the concept given here (http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html) to keep the ratio.

http://jsfiddle.net/vleong2332/4Lft1qdy/2/

## HTML changes

```
<div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!--Left Col-->
      <div class="container">
          <div class="inner_container" id="container1">
              .
              .
          </div>
      </div>
```

`

## CSS changes

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
.container:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;
}
.inner_container {
    background-size:100% auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border:5px solid #187BB7;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
img.info-icon{
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1001;
  background-color:white;
  width: 7%;
}
#container1 .info-icon1{
  position: absolute;
  top: 65%;
  left: 70%;
}
```

According to that article, you insert a ::before pseudo-element inside the (outer) container that has 100% padding-top - this will push the height of the div to match the width in 1:1 ratio. the div that contains the image is then positioned absolutely to the left top corner. I hope the article makes sense.

As for the magnifying glass icons, I changed the positioning and the width to percentage so it adapts to the width of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/vecf7abj/21/

As mentioned above, this utilizes floats and widths percentages:

```
float:left;
width:50%;
```

Also cleaned up some other code to vertical align within that div.

Comment: this is almost what i wanted, but if you resize the window you will notice that the background image is cut off. Can we fix this? Thank you!

Comment: sorry plz disregard my last comment on your answer, i misunderstood the url you provided with the one that @LShetty did. His url is what i was referring to. Thx!